# "user with this username already exists" in DRF ModelSerializer if not specified explicitly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying understand why this error occurs even though I know how to resolve. Just trying to understand DRF and Django better.

JSON in this format comes from the FE:

```
{
  "username": "username_here",
  "password": "password_here"
}
```

I have this view:

```
class UserSigninTokenAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserSigninTokenSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = UserSigninTokenSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            return Response(new_data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Which uses this serializers:

```
class UserSigninTokenSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = USERS
        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
            'id'
        ]

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        user_qs = USERS.objects.filter(username__iexact=username)
        if user_qs.exists() and user_qs.count() == 1:
            user_obj = user_qs.first()
            password_passes = user_obj.check_password(password)
            if password_passes:
                """
                A number of checks here I removed to keep this clean,
                otherwise would just use /api/token/ to get a token.
                I want user checks to pass before issuing a token,
                because having the token is what indicates they are 
                logged in successfully.
                """
                token = RefreshToken.for_user(user_obj)
                return {
                    'refresh': str(token),
                    'access': str(token.access_token)
                }
            else:
                Services.user_attempts(user_obj)
        raise ValidationError({'error': '''
            The credentials provided are invalid.
            <br>Please verify the username and password are correct.
        '''})
```

The `username = CharField()` seems redundant to me. The [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) says:

> The `ModelSerializer` class provides a shortcut that lets you automatically create a `Serializer` class with fields that correspond to the Model fields.

I interpret this as saying just specifying the `field = []` in the `class Meta:` is sufficient for deserializing the JSON.

However, when I remove the `username = CharField()`, I get a:

```
{
    "username": [
        "user with this username already exists."
    ]
}
```

The [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly) for explicit specifications says:

> You can add extra fields to a `ModelSerializer` or override the default fields by declaring fields on the class, just as you would for a `Serializer` class.

This makes it sound optional, but apparently it is mandatory to specify it.

What am I missing here if someone wouldn't mind explaining?

Comment: What's your view is supposed to do? It seems now it only receives data, validates it, then returns the same data back. Normally, you want to do some interactions with database along the way (retrieve some instance or save a new one based on `request.data` etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a `ModelSerializer` with your model and request is `POST`, there is no wonder why you are getting this.

`ModelSerializer` is used to provide a quick standard serialization for CRUD operations, so when your request is `POST` your serializer will assume that you are creating a new user with the request data for Users model, so creating validations will be applied and as username is unique..., you now the rest of the story.

Try to use a basic Serializer as you only want to read data it will be simpler

Comment: Got it, that makes sense now. Thanks for explaining!